# Proving an equality about primes

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to understand the following equality:

$$2 \prod_{\substack{p\vert h \\ p>2}} \Big( \frac{p-1}{p-2} \Big) \prod_{3 \leq p \leq z} \frac{p(p-2)}{(p-1)^2} \prod_{p \leq z}\Big(1-\frac{1}{p}\Big)^2 = \\ = 2 \prod_{\substack{p\vert h \\ p>2}} \Big( \frac{p-1}{p-2} \Big) \prod_{p>2} \frac{p(p-2)}{(p-1)^2}(1+O(z^{-1}))\prod_{p \leq z}\Big(1-\frac{1}{p}\Big)^2.$$

where $h \in \mathbb{N}$ is even, $z \in \mathbb{R}$ is "large enough" and $p$ is a prime.

The only thing that changes is the product of $\frac{p(p-2)}{(p-1)^2}$ which is extended to all primes and it add that "error term", which, intuitively, makes sense, but I don't really understand why the error term is precisely that one.

I searched for this in some books and articles, but every author uses different approximations, so I don't really know where to look for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio of the products in the last two expressions is

\begin{eqnarray}
\prod_{p\gt z}\frac{p(p-2)}{(p-1)^2}
&=&
\prod_{p\gt z}\left(1-\frac1{(p-1)^2}\right)
\\
&\gt&
\prod_{n=z}^\infty\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)
\\
&=&
\exp\left(\sum_{n=z}^\infty\log\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)
\\
&\gt&
\exp\left(-2\sum_{n=z}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\right)
\\
&\gt&
\exp\left(-2\int_{z-.1}^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^2}\right)
\\
&=&
\exp\left(-\frac2{z-1}\right)
\\
&=&
1+O\left(z^{-1}\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

I don’t know about the first question. These aren’t related; I think you should post them as separate questions.

Comment: My idea is to multiply and divide by $\prod_{p>z} \frac{p(p-2)}{(p-1)^2}$, so I need to work with $(\prod_{p>z} \frac{p(p-2)}{(p-1)^2})^{-1}$, but it seems that I can prove that using the same ideas you showed me, thank you. I'll write another post for the first question, so that this can be closed.